# Insert and remove Template textbox column in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, templatefield

```
class TextColumn : ITemplate
    {
        private string controlId;
        private string cssClass;

        public TextColumn(string id, string cssClass = "inputFromTo")
        {
            controlId = id;
            this.cssClass = cssClass;
        }

        public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();

            txt.ID = controlId;
            txt.CssClass = cssClass;

            container.Visible = true;

            container.Controls.Add(txt);
        }
    }

/************************************ Add column code snippet ****************************/

TemplateField dentry = new TemplateField();

TemplateField dexit = new TemplateField();

TemplateField dslack = new TemplateField();


dentry.ItemTemplate = new TextColumn("txtHH" + nameCount + "DEntry");

dexit.ItemTemplate = new TextColumn("txtHH" + nameCount + "DExit");

dslack.ItemTemplate = new TextColumn("txtHH" + nameCount + "DSlack");


gvOfcBlowingReport.Columns.Insert(startPoint, dentry);

gvOfcBlowingReport.Columns.Insert(startPoint + 1, dexit);

gvOfcBlowingReport.Columns.Insert(startPoint + 2, dslack); 


/********************************* Remove column code snippet ************************/

gvOfcBlowingReport.Columns.RemoveAt(startPoint - 1);

gvOfcBlowingReport.Columns.RemoveAt(startPoint - 2);

gvOfcBlowingReport.Columns.RemoveAt(startPoint - 3); 



// after executing this code all the columns vanish.
```

Anyone know how to remove this text box template column?

In the above code I am adding templated field textbox and later on removing the same on button click but due to some reason all the templated field are getting affected and returning `null` when i am using FindControl in grid. In display also grid is displayed as empty.

Some other people are also facing the same problem over http://forums.asp.net/t/1162011.aspx but so far no valuable solution.